# Grunt build to nginx causes errors (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs, nginx, gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I have a simple `AngularJS` application for which I used `grunt serve` to scaffold the code and test it. I now want the code deployed to a server using `nginx` and I'm doing it with the `grunt build` task which generates the code in the `./dist` folder. I now want this code transferred to the server where it can be hosted.

I don't know if the error is related to minifying the code, but the app doesn't run.

The errors are:

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a
    at http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:3:30474
    at http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:13890
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:13194)
    at http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:13985
    at c (http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:13194)
    at d (http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:13440)
    at Object.e [as instantiate] (http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:13587)
    at http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:29734
    at http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:4:22719
    at f (http://localhost/kds/scripts/ded94bd9.vendor.js:3:30909)
```

What's going wrong here?

**EDIT** Also, on the Chrome network log: http://cl.ly/image/3z0v3X2n1f3h

And the conf section of `nginx.conf`:

```
    location /kds/ {
            alias /Users/asheshambasta/code/kds/dist/;
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

And `grunt serve` loads up the application without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see an error in AngularJS like "Unknown provider: aProvider <- a" or "Unknown provider: nProvider <- n", it means the AngularJS dependency injection system was not able to match an argument to a provider. This error is legitimate when you have an argument in an injected function that does not exist, **but...**

It more often than that, means your AngularJS code was minified, which requires some work. You will have to annotate your controllers/services/etc in a certain way for AngularJS's dependency injection system to find it. See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) (search for "minification") for more details, but here's a quick rundown:

```
// This injects $scope and $http as the two arguments to the controller.
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) { ... }]);
```

The other option is to disable minification in your build configuration.

Comment: Well, right now, I also have problems which are more basic than that. I've disabled all minification steps in the build and yet I get errors like `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/kds/styles/main.css`, the same goes for `main.js` and any javascript files.

Comment: That is unrelated to the minification errors! Sounds like an error in your nginx paths configuration.

Comment: I don't think so, checking my `dist` folder, I actually see none of these files.